# Nlog not logging custom logs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nlog

I can see that nlog works because my log file is getting bigger but only some stuff is logged like app is starting, route is change and similar.

However, whereever I put `logger.LogCritical` or some other custom log method it does not work.

I am using ASP.NET COre 3.1 and latest NLog.

Here is my startup code:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder( string[] args ) =>
     Host.CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
       .ConfigureWebHostDefaults( webBuilder =>
       {
           webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
       } )
       .ConfigureLogging( logging =>
       {
           logging.ClearProviders();
           logging.SetMinimumLevel( Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace );
           logging.AddNLog( "nlog.config" );
       } );
```

And nlog.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file  -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I use it like this in controller:

```
           logger.LogInformation( "test critical IN CONTROLLER" );
```

And here it is how it is injected into contructor:

```
  public AuthController( IMediator mediator, ILogger<AuthController> logger )
        {
            this.mediator = mediator;
            this.logger = logger;
        }
```

I can see him:
[image]

but there is no log. Even not in log-all.txt file which will log everything regardless of trace level

Here is my appsettings.json

```
  "Logging": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Oh, since this injects NLog to Microsoft's logging infrastructure, check your `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`. The logging config in appsettings are applied first before being passed into NLog, so check if that is filtering out things before they reach NLog.

Comment: PS: Your `nlog.config` looks fine and works for me, so that's unlikely to be the source of the issue. See if there's any other filtering on the Microsoft layer.

Comment: I don't think so, because there is trace log level. I updated my question

Comment: Did you check `appsettings.Development.json`? This has bit me more than once. In the Visual Studio IDE you have to EXPAND `appsettings.json` to see the version that is actually used during debug.